# How to make admin change_view with a field clickable link to object

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-admin

How to make admin change_view with a field clickable link to the object of User or any other?
Like: `<a href="/admin/user/{{owner.id}}/change">{{owner.fullname}}</a>`

Currently there only simple text with id.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Car(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="cars", null=True, blank=True)

class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


admin.site.register(Car, CarAdmin)
```

Found a lot of example for list_view, but not for change_view.

UPD: Tried to add the following method to CarAdmin but it didn't help.

```
from django.utils.html import format_html


class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def owner_change_url(self, obj):
        return format_html('<a href="/admin/base/user/%s/change/">%s</a>' % (obj.owner.id, obj.owner.full_name))
    owner_change_url.short_description = 'Owner'
```

Comment: try `raw_id_fields` ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields)) instead of the default pull-down menu you get normally on a ForeignKey field. If that's not the widget you want, you can override with `formfield_overrides`

Comment: @dirkgroten, I need the opposite way. I can have either ID, or value by this id. But how to add "<a href="/admin/user/{{id}}/change">{{name}}</a>"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a *read-only* field which links to your user. Inside your `CarAdmin` class:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    readonly_fields = ('user_link', )

    @mark_safe
    def user_link(self, car):
        url = reverse('admin:user_user_change', args=(car.owner.id, ))
        return '<a href="{url}">{user}</a>'.format(
             url=url, 
             user=car.owner.fullname
        )

    user_link.short_description = "Edit car owner"
```

Comment: Tried that method - but it didn't help. Maybe something else should be changed/configured?

Comment: What do you mean “didn’t help”?

Comment: The field did not become clickable

Comment: This is an additional link that should show up at the bottom of your change page (if you didn’t define `fields` or `fieldsets` otherwise make sure you add `user_link`). It won’t change the original field.

Comment: `user_link` didn't appear as well, but what I wanted - to make existing field clickable.

Comment: I don't understand, if you use a `raw_id_field`, you get an input field, next to it a 'search' button and next to it the exact link to the object you want. [example here](http://tinypic.com/r/1z4wkys/9)